# observe(callbacks), know when CRUD event comes form client (local) o server (remote)

Tags: meteor

if apply observer to a Collection, I don't want repeat two times the same thing on local.

**Example on a diagram CRUD operation (a diagram is made of elements)**

*Local*

1. Add/remove/edit a element (gui)
2. Intercept event and make Add/remove/edit on Collection (each element is a document)
3. Obeserver catch event on Collection WRONG!

*Remote*

1. Observer catch event on Collection
2. Add/remove/edit a element (gui)

Answer (score 1):

I have find a solution (workaround).

I have add an user field to document. This store the user that make the CRUD event.

In the observer I check document.user

`if(document.user != Meteor.userId()) // remote CRUD`